# Sed or awk: how to call line addresses from separate file?

Tags: sed, awk

I have 'file1' with (say) 100 lines. I want to use sed or awk to print lines 23, 71 and 84 (for example) to 'file2'. Those 3 line numbers are in a separate file, 'list', with each number on a separate line.

When I use either of these commands, only line 84 gets printed:

```
for i in $(cat list); do sed -n "${i}p" file1 > file2; done

for i in $(cat list); do awk 'NR==x {print}' x=$i file1 > file2; done
```

Can a for loop be used in this way to supply line addresses to sed or awk?

Comment: Yes and DON'T!!! See @Jaypal's answer for the correct way to do what you want.

Comment: @Ed Norton - I've tried all the suggested solutions and they all work. For my particular problem (different from the simplified one I posted), the ideal solution is perreal's.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/&p/' list | sed -nf - file1 >file2
```

Use `list` to build a `sed` script.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `>` after the loop in order to capture everything. Since you are using it inside the loop, the file gets overwritten. Inside the loop you need to do `>>`.

Good practice is to or use `>` outside the loop so the file is not open for writing during every loop iteration.

However, you can do everything in `awk` without `for loop`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}FNR in a' list file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Means alot coming from the master himself. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to `>>`(append to the file) . But you are overwriting the file. That is why, You are always getting 84 line only in the file2.

Try use,

```
for i in $(cat list); do sed -n "${i}p" file1 >> file2; done
```

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
 sed -n $(sed -e 's/^/-e /' -e 's/$/p/' list) input
```

given the example input, the inner command create a string like this: `

```
-e 23p 
-e 71p 
-e 84p
```

so the outer sed then prints out given lines

Comment: I'd use pipe and `sed -f -` instead.

Comment: like this: `sed -e 's/^/-e /' -e 's/$/p/' list | sed -f - -n list`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid running sed/awk in a for/while loop altgether:

```
# store all lines numbers in a variable using pipe
lines=$(echo $(<list) | sed 's/ /|/g')

# print lines of specified line numbers and store output
awk -v lineS="^($lines)$" 'NR ~ lineS' file1 > out
```